# Adding moving circle overly on MKMapView on iOS 16 and above

Tags: ios, swiftui, mkmapview, overlay, mkcircle

I want to add a moving circle on MKMapView it will remain in the centre of the map and start moving when the user moves the map and zoom in and zoom out when the user zooms in/out the map I am able to achieve this by using the centre coordinate of the map but when I move the app it is flickering as I am removing and adding the MKCircle overlay when the coordinate changes

**What I want to achieve:-** A moving circle/Annotation on top of the mapview which moves/zoom along with mapview

Here is the code

**Adding pan gesture and circle overlay here**

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        mapView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.showsCompass = false

let panGesture =  UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(context.coordinator.addPinBasedOnGesture(_:)))
       panGesture.delegate = context.coordinator
      mapView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
        
        return mapView
}
```

**Adding and removing method which updated the moving circle coordinate to**

```
func updateMovingCircle(regionToUpdate: MKCoordinateRegion, view: MKMapView) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            addMovingCircle(to: view, movingLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: regionToUpdate.center.latitude, longitude: regionToUpdate.center.longitude), radius: radius)
        }
    }
```

**func to add and remove circle**

```
func addMovingCircle(to view: MKMapView, movingLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius: Int) {
        for overlay in overlays where overlay.title == "1" {
            view.removeOverlay(overlay)
        }
        let radius: Double = Double(radius) * 1.5
        let movingCircle = MKCircle(center: movingLocation, radius: radius * 1000)
        movingCircle.title = "1"
        view.addOverlay(movingCircle)
    }
```

**gesture recognizer delegate method on coordinator**

```
 @objc func addPinBasedOnGesture(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if let mapView = gestureRecognizer.view as? MKMapView {
          mapViewController.updateMovingCircle(regionToUpdate: mapView.region, view: mapView)
        }
    }
    
    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

**Overlay renderer**

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {        
        
        if let circleOverlay = overlay as? MKCircle {
            let circleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: circleOverlay)
            circleRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor(Color.SG.purple)
            circleRenderer.lineWidth = 2
            circleRenderer.lineDashPattern = [2, 5]
            return circleRenderer
        }
        
        return MKOverlayRenderer()
    }
```

This code is working but the experience is not smooth and circle is flickering

Comment: It's hard to imagine your aim. Can you share an image/screenshot of what're you trying to do? I am assuming a kind of annotation that is always center the map whenever dragging/zooming right?

Comment: Yes correct, I want a circle overlay/annotation on the map view which moves when the user moves the map and remains centred on the map

Comment: There are two possible approaches - The simplest is to use the map view `regionDidChange` delegate method to update the overlay only once the zoom/pan is finished (you need to do this anyway because your pan gesture won't capture the movement of the map in the deceleration phase). The harder way is to add an overlay  as son suggested, but you need to take the distance based on the [zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44674911/swift-mkmapview-get-zoom-level-width-or-radius-of-visible-map-area-from-latitud) into account

Answer (score 0):

I would like to go with a different approach. You can add the entire MapView inside a ZStack and a `MKCircle` above the map. Then, no matter how you interact with the map, MKCircle will stay at the center.

```swift
var body: some View {
    @State private var zoomFactor: Double = 10

    ZStack {
        MapViewSUI(zoomFactor: $zoomFactor)

        Image(systemName: "mappin.circle")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 64 * (zoomFactor / 10), height: 64 * (zoomFactor / 10))
            .foregroundColor(.red)
    }
}
```

---

**Updated:** Here is the idea for zoom action

- Declare a @State property to pass in MapViewSUI which presents MKCircle size.
- Whenever the map's region changes, calculate the zoom factor and assign it to this @State to update MKCircle size.

```swift
struct MapViewSUI: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var zoomFactor: Double
    ...
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        var map: MapViewSUI
        ...
        //This is formula to calculate zoom level and it is not my code
        func getZoomLevel(from mapView: MKMapView) -> Double {
            log2(360 * ((mapView.frame.size.width/256.0) / mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta));
        }

        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
            map.zoomFactor = getZoomLevel(from: mapView)
        }
    }
}
```

You may want to change the view size or add animation if needed. Output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: But it will not zoom in/out with the map view zoom in/out, I tried that but it remains fixed

Comment: Oh I forgot the zoom action. I'm updating, you will need to handle map delegation here. Btw, what is the most/least zoom in/out factor that applies to the `maker`?

Comment: It has the same zoom level as Mep